# Simplest way to log file read operations

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems

I need to make my app capable to log file read operations (made from all running applications). Suggest a simplest way to do this, plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can be used:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for sounds immense, since there isn't really a "simplest way to do this".

I reckon you want functionality similar to [Process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

Why not run that utility and somehow hook up your application to it?

Comment: Well, it's file monitoring capability is the same what I need. I suppose there is some ready-made framework to do the same functionality. Maybe some API hooking or something like this.

Comment: I don't think, that there is such a ready-made framework. Process Monitor is the only tool that can do such things, and its quite well known for its capabilities. Such things are quite difficult.